# How can you add environment variables in a Jenkins Multibranch Pipeline

Tags: django, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I am working on a Django project, I have integrated it withJenkins Multibranch Pipeline. I cannot inject environment variables by the Multibrach Pipeline option even after installing the Environment Injector plugin.

I have evironment variables like DB_PASSWORD that must be included in the envvars.

Any insight will be highly appreciated.

Comment: you can add them as project parameters and then simply refer them by $varName. did you try this?

Comment: Do `withEnv` and `withCredentials` not work for you?

Comment: @SVMadhavaReddy how can you refer them in Jenkinsfile?

Comment: @mkobit I know that option but how can I add it in my Jenkinsfile since you cannot add directly to the Jenkins Multibranch project?

Comment: @mkobit  ` withEnv(['DB_PASSWORD=password']) {
            sh '''
                virtualenv venv
                . venv/bin/activate
                python manage.py collectstatic --noinput
                deactivate
               '''
        }`     worked but the problem is I am exposing my DB_PASSWORD value to the public, thanks for the previous insight.

Comment: @ERICKMWAZONGA if you provide them with the project parameters, they will be available as env params. so please access using the language env variable accessing strategy.

Comment: @SVMadhavaReddy I get your point but I don't have any idea on how to do that, I have researched but in vain....could you elaborate, please?

Answer (score 1):

Since you require secrets, the best practice way is to use the withCredentials plugin which can load credentials stored in Jenkins credential store and expose them as ENV variables to code executed within its block/closure. Using withCredentials does not expose them in Jenkins logs

```
withCredentials([[$class: 'UsernamePasswordMultiBinding',
credentialsId: 'DB_Creds', 
usernameVariable: 'DB_USERNAME', 
passwordVariable: 'DB_PASSWORD']]) {// do stuff }
```

For non sensitive Env vars use withEnv

```
withEnv(["AWS_REGION=${params.AWS_REGION}"]) {// do stuff }
```

If for whatever reason you want Env vars set across your entire pipeline (not entirely recommended but sometimes necessary):

```
env.MY_VAR='var'
echo("My Env var = ${env.MY_VAR}")
```